# i18n in Symfony Forms

Tags: forms, symfony1, localization, internationalization, symfony-1.4

Is there any way I can use the `format_number_choice` function inside of a actions file. In fact I need to use it for a Form error message.

```
'max_size' => 'File is too large (maximum is %max_size% bytes).',
```

In English it's simply "bytes", but in other languages the syntax changes after a certain value (for example if the number is greater than 20 it's: "20 **of** bytes").

I can use parenthesis, of course, but if the framework offers support for doing this specific thing, why not to use it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it's currently implemented in the 1.4 branch, you can define only one translation per message using il18n XML files.

What you could do is create a custom validator which inherits the current validator (`sfValidatorFile` in your example) and does the size checking in the `doClean` method before calling its parent's method.

I suggest you take a look at the source to see how it works : [sfValidatorFile](http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.4/lib/validator/sfValidatorFile.class.php)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle number ranges for translation is [explained here in the Definitive Guide](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/13-I18n-and-L10n#chapter_13_sub_handling_complex_translation_needs). I won't reproduce it here as the documentation itself is clear and concise. Note however that the string is not extracted automatically by the i18n-extract task, so you need to add it manually - again, the documentation explains this.

**So yes**, you can use the `format_number_choice()` function inside an action - you just need to load the helper inside the action like this:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('I18N');
```

Comment: That's for actions in general. I need to use the `format_number_choice()` for a validator's error message.